# Do we need the [bootup] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Looking at the questions tagged with [bootup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bootup), I concluded the tag is synonymous to [boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/boot). Unlike [boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/boot), it has no description and is much less used and mostly by low-rep (assuming: new) users. Is it possible to make it a true synonym?

Comment: seems like a horrible ugly non-word. Get rid of it however possible please

Comment: Created synonym suggestion: http://askubuntu.com/tags/boot/synonyms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tada!

```
updating post history, 31 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 24 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 23 rows affected
updating Documentation tag proposal commitments, 0 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, new count: 12944
tag remapping of [boot] and [bootup] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym bootup -> boot was approved!
```